# ERROR : Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to INT

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to pass few parameters from one page to another by this codes (1st page):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   Response.Redirect(string.Format("../ShowResult.aspx?&Name{0}&Finalfrom={1}&Finalto{2}",
        Name.Text,
        Paidfrom.Text,
        Paidto.Text));
}
```

at the 2nd page I have a GridView to show the result and here is my SqlDataSource connection:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [CaseNumber], [Name] FROM [Files] WHERE
    (@Name IS NULL OR Name LIKE '%' + @Name + '%') AND 
    (@CaseNumber IS NULL OR CaseNumber LIKE '%' +  @CaseNumber + '%') AND 
    (@paid IS NULL OR  paid BETWEEN '@paidfrom' AND '@paidto' ) AND);"
    CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False">
```

I have the same error even when I tried CONVERT function!
so can anybody bright me up?

Comment: Is CaseNumber an int? You can't do a conditional check like that with an integer datatype. You would have to cast is a varchar to check like that. CAST(CaseNumber as varchar(10)) like ...

Comment: yes CaseNumber in an int. but the problem actually is about @Paidfrom and @Paidto!  here is my error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@Paidfrom' to data type int.

Comment: LOL. You have your parameter wrapped in single quotes. It should be "BETWEEN @paidfrom AND @paidto". Otherwise it is using string literal and not parameters.

Comment: I think the single quotes around `@paidfrom` and `@paidto` makes them into string literals.

Comment: omitting quotes causes another error :Must declare the scalar variable "@Paidfrom ang double quotes syntax error !!!

Comment: Well....do you have that parameter defined?

Comment: yes I do! it comes from a textbox

Comment: You obviously do not have that parameter defined. Can you share the parameters definition for your DataSource? I see that you have passed the value to the page via query string but there is no where we see where you setup the sql parameters.

Comment: yes you where right! I forgot to define datasource parameter for that one! thank for your attention you are my man! ;)

Comment: You are welcome. Glad you got it working.